# Learning Desktop Application Security

Tags: appsec

I am familiar with web security but I would like to know more about non-web application security.

I know about memory corruption vulnerabilities like buffer overflow and buffer overread and how serious they are. But how about Java/C# or similar applications, where memory corruption vulnerabilities are far less common.

I'm assuming you could test for all server-side vulnerabilities like SQL-injection or OS-command injection like you test on a web app. I also know that Java/C# apps could be vulnerable to insecure deserialization. But what else could a desktop app pentester check?

Is there any training provider for desktop app security like how it is Portswigger for web security? Is there a methodology or even a checklist of what you could check?

Comment: You mean like: https://owasp.org/www-project-desktop-app-security-top-10/ I googled "pentest desktop application" and got a ton of hits for articles, frameworks, andd courses.

Comment: It turns out that I was actually asking about what's called "Thick Client Security". The best resource that I found is the following: [Thick Client Penetration Testing Methodology](https://www.cyberark.com/resources/threat-research-blog/thick-client-penetration-testing-methodology)